# Adding local images to react / redux reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is my first stack overflow question.

Currently I am trying to add local images from the img folder onto my reducer.

Is there a way to add local images to the react / redux reducer or would I have to upload them online as thumbnails and link them from there?

Please let me know and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the command line `create-react-app` from npm you can just import the image in your code and it will be available. If you don't know what i am talking about you could use `create-react-app` to make your app

Answer (score 0):

Put you image in you src--folder. example img01.png and use as follow.

```js
import IMG from './image/img01.png';
```

then you can use it as :

```js
<img src={IMG} alt="img />
```

If you are talking about reducer dispatch the you will dispatch string like "./image/img01.png" and make a import as per components need.